# rename only the last directory in the tree

Tags: unix

The below command in unix will rename all the directory with the name `Utility` to `Claim`, when executed from the top level

```
 find . -type d -name Utility -exec sh -c 'mv "${0}" "${0%/Utility}/Claim"' {} \;
```

However I just want to rename the directory at the last level of `Utility`, not all. Example if the structure is `/Sample/Utility/version1/Utility/test.txt`, I want to rename only the last `Utility` folder, when executed from the top level.

Comment: Can the Utility folder to rename contain other folders? Can you say anything about the folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```
find . -type d -name Utility -print | sort -r | awk '{if(substr(p,1,length($0))!=$0) print $0; p=$0}' | while read i; do echo mv "${i}" "${i%Utility}Claim"; done
```

`find` is used to find all directory named Utility in the current folder and print the found names.
The names are sorted in reverse order.
`awk` prints only those lines (names) that are not a prefix of the previous line (name). This is the step that for example removes "/Sample/Utility" when found after "/Sample/Utility/version1/Utility".
The lines are read in a shell loop and then I print out the mv commands that you want. Remove the "echo" to do the `mv`s.